# Ubuntu 18.04 - one CPU core is always warmer

Tags: gnome, 18.04, cpu, temperature

I recently began searching for a good Linux distribution and took a look at several of them. I'm currently set on the standard Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, but there is one thing that's troubling me.

All diagnostic programs show one of my CPU cores is running at a higher frequency than the other and it's warmer by about 6 degrees Celsius.

My hardware: Thinkpad X230, i5 3320m, 8 GB RAM.

[screenshot with i7z showing CPU core speed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVSeN.png)

[screenshot with a look at the cores' temperatures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74yt9.png)

Looking at process monitors, such as htop, don't seem to show any suspicious activity, like a process running on that second core alone. Other distros I tested include Manjaro, KDE Neon, Mint Cinnamon and Ubuntu Mate - all of which had the temperatures at idle spread more evenly. Dual booting with Windows and leaving it idle for a few minutes also shows both cores at similar temperatures, +/- 1 degree.

I can post any additional logs, etc. when needed for further diagnosis.

Comment: I don't think 45C vs 51C as a burning issue (pun noted).

Comment: Well, yes and no ;) The difference might not be substantial enough to be worrisome, however, other distros and Windows seem to distribute the temperatures more evenly. And, of course, I'm talking about idle temps - I know that depending on load, one core that is used more will get warmer than the other. Ubuntu doesn't seem to calm down and stop doing something with the second core.